# Using setTimeout to delay loop iteration

Tags: javascript

I would like to delay my `while` loop on each iteration. I tried the following:

```
var o = 1;
while(o<4){
    setTimeout("setupAnimation(o)",2000);
    //setupAnimation(o); //<--this works but everything happens att the same time
    o++;
}
```

I also tried to write it like this, which didn't work either:

```
var o = 1;
function repeatMe(){
    setupAnimation(o);
    o++;
    setTimout('repeatMe()',1000);
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eval` is slow, hard to debug and has potential security problems (depending on where the data comes from). Don't use it. (Passing a string to `setTimeout` uses `eval` by proxy.)

Pass a function to `setTimeout` instead. You'll need to use a closure to capture the current value of `o` for the function you pass.

You should probably also use a `for` loop here instead of a `while` loop. The syntax is clearer.

```
function setupAnimationFactory(o) {
    return function() {
        setupAnimation(o);
    }
}

for (var o = 0; o < 4; o++){
    setTimeout(setupAnimationFactory(o),2000);
}
```

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding this, this is just going to delay the entire thing by 2 seconds rather than spacing out each call.  Equivalent to just setting timeout once for the entire thing.  I took the question to mean he wanted to space out the iterations.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var o = 1;
function repeatMe(){
    setupAnimation(o);
    o++;
    setTimeout(function(){repeatMe();},1000);
}

repeatMe();
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use the second approach here's the working Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var o = 1; 
    function repeatMe(){ 

    setupAnimation(o); 
    o++; 

    setTimout(repeatMe(),1000); 
    } 

    function setupAnimation(o){
        alert(o);
    }

    </script>

<a href='#' onclick="repeatMe()">Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var o = 1;  //Global Variable
var animTimerId;  //Global Variable

function setupAnimation(o){
   // Your code goes here

   o++;
   if(o == 4){
     clearTimeout(animTimeoutId);
     break;
   }
}

function repeatMe(){
   animTimeoutId = setTimeout("setupAnimation(o)",2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
setTimeout(function(){ myFunction(parameter)}, timeoutLength);
```

Comment: That won't work, since `o` is in a loop and will change to the last value before any of the timeouts hit 0.

Comment: Yes, good spot. However, you could declare a variable in the scope of the anonymous function to transfer o as the parameter, I think.